# Best bet for elastic search using search api

Tags: 8, search

I am using elastic search with search_api module. I found https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_best_bets module which seems to work only with solr instance. Is there other way to do best bets using elastic search or is there any way I can create my own Query Handler extension for elastic search. Have anyone worked already on this? Please suggest.

Thanks,

CIsSharp

Comment: Does elasticsearch support such a concept? I couldn't find much on google apart from people asking if it does (without response). If you know how to formulate a query to the search backend that gets the results you need, it shouldn't be too difficult to create your own (or augment an existing) query handler

Comment: There is a boost parameter to use for boosting search field. I wonder if that can help. But my issue is if it is for a field level then it will effect every nodes.